# How to validate multiple textboxes in tabs plugin with only one property in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tabs. In each tab I have a textbox with validation.

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<style>
    .tabs li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    .tabs a {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .tabs a.active {
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
        }
</style>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <ul class='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='tab1'>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div id='tab2'>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
                // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                // which tab is active and it's associated content
                var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content = $($active.attr('href'));

                // Hide the remaining content
                $links.not($active).each(function () {
                    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                });

                // Bind the click event handler
                $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                    // Make the old tab inactive.
                    $active.removeClass('active');
                    $content.hide();

                    // Update the variables with the new link and content
                    $active = $(this);
                    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                    // Make the tab active.
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content.show();

                    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is what gets rendered for both tabs:

```
<div id="tab1">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

The difference are these two:

```
data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required."
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

What I want to do is to have validation for both textboxes independently och each other. That is, when the user clicks on the first tab I want to be able to validate the textbox in the first tab and if the user clicks on the second tab I want to validate the textbox in the second tab.

How to do this with only one property in my viewmodel class? Imagine having 50 tabs. I wouldn't want to have 50 properties in my viewmodel class.

Comment: Can your action method be made to accept a List<string> instead of a simple string?

Comment: You *could* write some JS to selectively turn off/on validation on the fields depending on which tab is active (tie into the tab activation event, or create your own). However, your real problem here is one of bad design. The same field *should not* be in 50 tabs. If that field is shared with all tabs, take it out of the tab and only put fields specific to the tabs in the each tab.

Comment: I am not really sure I follow you..? But yes, it can be made to accept  a List<string> if that's what's required for this to work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I see your point. I have a couple of textboxes (firstname, lastname, address, zipcode and city) that reoccur in four tabs. I do @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName) for all of the four textboxes (in different tabs). Is it better to do it like this: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstNameTab1), @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstNameTab2), @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstNameTab3) and @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstNameTab4)?

Comment: Then the user submits the form, do you want only one of the tabs to be submitted? If not, you are doing it completely wrong.

Comment: Yes, only one of the tabs will be submitted.

Comment: Sounds like you need to have one form per tab then...